# Are there limits to the CIT environment HERE Maps API?

Tags: here-api

Specifically, I'm looking to see if there are any rate limits or max request limits on the use of the CIT (testing) environment for their REST API.  I am looking at running a geocoder test for a larg-ish sized dataset and didn't find any specifics on the developer documentation site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIT is not intended for high usage/load testing and not covered by SLA, it means that there might be limitations. It's described in docs here https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/common/request-cit-environment-rest.html

In case if you have lot's of data, maybe it make sense to try Batch Geocoding https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/introduction.html